# Clarification on View vs View controller lifecycle

Tags: ios

Can someone confirm if my understanding is correct?

#### Lifecycle for initialization

- View controller being initialized **DOES NOT** mean the view has been initialized
- View being initialized **DOES** mean the view controller has been initialized

#### Lifecycle for destruction

- View controller being still alive **DOES NOT** mean the view is also still alive
- View being still alive **DOES** mean the view controller is also still alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do "initialized" and "alive" mean? Don't think in those terms; think in terms of what the view controller events tell you:

- `viewDidLoad` means the view controller has acquired its main view.
- `viewWillAppear` means the main view is about to appear in the interface.
- `viewWillDisappear` means the main view is about to disappear from the interface.
- `deinit` means the view controller is going out of existence. At this point you can still refer to the `view`.

Another way to look at is: for a correctly managed view controller, the view controller will get into the view controller hierarchy and its view will get into the interface, and the reverse when the view controller is no longer needed.

Comment: Just to clarify `At this point you can still refer to the view.` means that the view and my `weak IBOutlets` wont be `nil` correct?

Comment: Correct, just as for any properties during `deinit`. A view controller treats its view just like any class treats any instance property. It just acquires the view lazily, that’s all.